# How can I use the sequential criterion to prove/disprove the existence of a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

In my book (Abbott), it is written that the sequential criterion for the limit of a sequence is as much of a tool to prove as it is to disprove the existence of a limit.

My question is: how?

For example, if I had
 $$f(x) = x^2$$ and wanted to prove that $$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 4$$ exists, how would I do so?

or How could i disprove the existence of $$f(x) = \cfrac{1}{x-2}$$, $$\lim _{x \to 2} f(x)$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you saw the proof, simply you need to consider all sequence $x_n$ which converge to $x_0$, if for each sequence that been mentioned $f(x_n)$ converge to $f(x)$ then you are done. As far as I know it's not that practical in proving limit exists, but in the other direction it's very handy.

Example: 
$sin(\frac{1}{x})$ to show limit does not exist when $x \rightarrow 0$ consider these sequences: $x_n= \frac{1}{n\pi}$ and $x_n =\frac{2}{n\pi} $ both of them approaching 0

Answer (score 1):

For the first limit, take any sequence $\left \{ x_{n} \right \}_{n\geq 0}$ such  that $x_{n}\rightarrow 2$. Let $\epsilon >0$ be given and consider

$\vert x_{n}^{2}-4\vert =\vert (x_{n}+2)(x_{n}-2)\vert$. Since  $x_{n}\rightarrow 2$, we can choose $N$ large enough so that $\vert (x_{n}+2)\vert <5$ and $\vert (x_{n}-2))\vert<\epsilon/5$ whenever $n>N$. This means that $\vert f(x_{n})-4\vert =\vert (x_{n}+2)(x_{n}-2)-4\vert<\epsilon$. So since $f(x_{n})\rightarrow 4$ , the limit is indeed $4$.

Now, we claim that the second limit cannot be finite. For this, we fix an arbitrary real number $M$ and produce a sequence $x_{n}$ such that $x_{n}\rightarrow 2$ and yet $\vert f(x_{n})\vert >M$ if $n$ is large enough. You can check that $x_{n}=2+1/n$ will do the trick.

Comment: I do not understand the justification on how you handled the second question.

Afterfall, if we did the same thing for question 1, using $M=3$ would we not get the same result, with $|f(x_n)| > 3$

Comment: In question 1 you are proving the existence of a limit, while in question 2 you are saying there is no limit, In the former case, we are proving that if x is close to $2$ then $f(x)$ is close to $4$. In the second case, we found a sequence that whose values at $f$ do not get close to ANY number.